# java using txt on an afp server

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, bufferedreader, afp

I've been using my raspberry pi to build an afp (apple filing protocol) server. Now I'm trying to use a txt file with java on my laptop. But it didn't work if I do this:

```
try{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("afp://.......1.txt"));
String line = reader.readLine();
System.out.println(line);
} catch(IOException e) {
System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

The result is "File not found". Does anyone know how it works?

```
File not found
java.io.FileNotFoundException: afp:/....1.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.example.pz.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: I've posted the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the java.io.File class supports the AFP protocol, out of the box.

As far as I am aware, java.io.File only supports local filesystems and UNC paths for CIFS and SMB shares.

A quick look around the web suggests that Jaffer brings AFP support to Java: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jaffer/

If you get it to work for you, you might consider adapting it to Apache Virtual Filesystem (VFS).